# Accessor Mutators in c# returning wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am using accessor/mutators in asp.net(C#) to assign and get values.

I have two events:

```
protected void ddlDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    accessVariables.DepID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDepartments.SelectedValue);
}
protected void chkIsHead_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(accessVariables.DepID);
}
```

It calls this:

```
public class AccessibleVariables
{
    public int depID { get; set; }
    public int DepID 
    {
        get { return depID; }
        set { depID = value; }
    }
 }
```

2nd event returns 0, why ?
i ran debugger, i checked, the (set) assigns the real value, that's perfect but get doesn't return real value, it returns 0 always, why ?

Comment: It's kind of weird that you have TWO public properties, basically named the same thing. your AccessibleVariables could be simplified to `public class AccessibleVariables { public int DeptID { get; set; } }`

Comment: well MSDN made the same weird mistake brother, 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @user3518032: you're looking at .NET 1.1 documentation. It's over a decade old.

Comment: Also, their first one is `private` - that used to be the way to do it before the property syntactic sugar: `private int _depID; public int DepID { get { return _depID; } set { _depID = value }; }` Anyway, not relevant to your question really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As http is stateless protocol the values of properties are not maintained within `postback` in asp.net. You can use `ViewState` to hold value between postback. You can make a int property on ViewState that will return int from getter and take int to set the `ViewState`.

```
ViewState["depID"] = "0";   
public int AccessibleVariables
{
    get { return (int) ViewState["depID"]; }
    set { ViewState["depID"] = value; }
}
```

**[ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3)**

> Microsoft® ASP.NET view state, in a nutshell, is the technique used by
>   an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form
>   across postbacks.

**[Stateless Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)**

> In computing, a stateless protocol is a communications protocol that
>   treats each request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to
>   any previous request so that the communication consists of independent
>   pairs of request and response. A stateless protocol does not require
>   the server to retain session information or status about each
>   communications partner for the duration of multiple requests